# How to programmatically set appointment's recipient display name in Outlook without creating a contact in address book

Tags: c#, outlook, addin-express

I am trying to achieve setting programmatically the display name of an appointment's recipient in Outlook without creating a contact for him. The desired result would be the following:

[image]

which can be achieved through Outlook UI by double clicking on the respective address in Address book dialog and setting the display name in the following dialog:

[image]

Using the following code, adds the new recipient to the Outlook appointment but does not set the required display name:

```
var appointmentItem = outlookApplication.ActiveInspector() as AppointmentItem;
var newRecipient = appointmentItem.Recipients.Add("john_smith@example.com");
newRecipient.AddressEntry.Name = "John Smith";
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the name in the form `"John Smith <john_smith@example.com>"`.